# Looking for examples of left side bar PLP filtering that needs an apply button

Tags: filter, e-commerce, b2b

Automatic filtering upon selection is not an option at this time. I'm Looking for good ux examples of left side bar PLP filtering that needs an apply button but that is on the left vertical filtering bar, aka not on top of the products on the right side. Make sense?

Thank you kindly for any help.